# Google play store still showing an update option for my react native app even though it is fully updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have uploaded my react native app on play store, and every time I download it, it shows an update option next to uninstall option instead of open option on play store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be facing the same problem like me,

`Version code` is the reason for it

> check your version code in `package.json` and `build.gradle` file,
>   they both should be same